# Hide full screen button on all Mac OS windows?

Tags: macos

Is it possible, natively via Preferences or otherwise, to hide the green Full Screen button that appears next to the Minimise and Close actions on a window?

I always click it by accident and never use the feature, so would like to remove it if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not possible** to remove the green, full screen button from an app window's title bar.

To stop an app from going full-screen you can tap and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, and the window will be maximized normally. (However, you won't remember to hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key when hitting the button accidentally).